# Rails 4 Api Users Post test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rails-api

I'm building a blog in Rails 4.2 API (for an Angular front end). I'm adding in users with devise (overkill I know), and my controller tests pass for everything. When I try a curl POST request or try to create a user from my Angular app, I get a 406 Not Acceptable status code.

Here is my create controller method:

```
def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
        render json: user, status: 201
    else
        render json: { errors: user.errors }, status: 422
    end
end

private
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

I am able to create users from the rails console without a problem.

Here is the curl command I keep trying:

```
curl -i -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json' -X POST -d '{"email":"person@mail.com","password":"12345678","password_confirmation":"12345678"}' http://api.myapi.dev/users
```

and I have this resource too:

```
api_users POST   /users(.:format)                            api/users#create {:subdomain=>"api"}
```

I can update a user, and perform any other action from curl without issue, I just don't see the problem here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), `406` response is:

> The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

So when you use cURL, you don't need to send `-H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-type: application/json`, Rails will automatically render the JSON result for you. Because you have only specified `format.json` in your controller.

Rails expects you to send the data in following way:

```
{ "users": { "email", "person@mail.com" }, ... }
```

While you are not sending `users` when you hit the server with the cURL command.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Removing the headers on other POST calls doesn't work either. I think I need them.

Comment: @baron816 I've edited my answer. Please check it out.

Comment: Thanks I got it now. Yeah it needs {"user": {...}}. I think I also needed to add in 

    DeviseController.respond_to :json

in the ApplicationController. It still seems to need the headers.

Comment: If you think, my answer is valid, and helped you, you can accept it.